# Arduino - fuse setting problem on ATmega328P-PU

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

I am trying to do fuse setting on ATmega328P-PU chips using an [avr programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071P2LCC9).

I was successfully able to do fuse setting on 3 ATmega328P-PU chips (which I bought from one of the sites - I forgot). So I bought three more [from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018ZR3F7O).

When I execute `avrdude -c usbasp -p m328p` on the previous 3 chips, I got this response, and was able to do fuse setting.

> avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
>   avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
>
> Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s
>
> avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
>
> avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FF, H:D9, L:E2)
>
> avrdude done.  Thank you.

But when I execute the same command on the 3 chips I recently bought, I am getting this.

```
avrdude -c usbasp -p m328p

avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
     Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
     this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I triple-checked the wiring and soldering area. They all look fine.

Is this because the 3 chips I recently bought have a bootloader?

The description for the chip that works is here.

[image]

Comment: These chips have been configured for a 16 MHz external oscillator. Are you providing an external clock source on your board?

Comment: No. there is no external clock on the board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chips configured with a bootloader would also have the fuses set for an external clock (the factory default is the on-chip oscillator). Without an external clock they won't work.

I have a [sketch that uploads files](http://www.gammon.com.au/uploader) that also can provide an external clock for this eventuality.

As mentioned on that page an 8 MHz clock is provided on pin D8 of the programming board, so you can connect to D8 on the Uno which you are running the sketch on to pin 9 on the actual Atmega328P chip.

Alternatively find a 16 MHz crystal or resonator and connect that between pins 9 and 10 of your Atmega328P which will provide the clock that it is expecting. If you use a crystal you should also run 22 pF capacitors between each leg and ground, like in this image:

[image: Atmega328 with crystal]